# A question about HTTP headers cache , expire 

Tags: apache, caching

If in .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf|ico)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 years"
</FilesMatch>
```

Headers in Browser:

```
Cache-Control:maxage=5184000
Expires:Thu, 20 Jan 2011 10:18:51 GMT
```

Then browser doesn't cache HTML code, does it?

And Google recommend send expire 1 month, why youtube send headers

```
Expires:Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the configuration directives you have provided with give browsers any information about how long you want the data to be cached for. The decision about caching the HTML or not will be down to any directives sent that are not covered by the config if your question and by browser settings.

I've never see a recommendation from Google to expire content after one month. Caching expiry should be based on how frequently the content changes. (Since YouTube data changes **very** frequently, with new videos and comments being added all the time, then "has already expired" is a sensible value for many YouTube pages).

Comment: "Set Expires to a minimum of one month, and preferably up to one year, in the future. (We prefer Expires over Cache-Control: max-age because it is is more widely supported.) Do not set it to more than one year in the future, as that violates the RFC guidelines." google recommend

Comment: i dont remember but many tool recommend > 1month >"<. I dont know how

Comment: @meotimdihia: Supplementary media like stylesheets, images, or scripts are not change that often. In most cases they are created once and not changed ever after. That’s why some recommend to set those files to never expire at all (use an expiration date more than one year in the future) and use a different file if the contents have changed (some use version information or unique tokens in the URL to make the resource yet unknown).

Comment: then i only can config in apache ?. but they recommend expire > 1month then how html can refresh O_O.

Comment: @meotimdihia: No. Most programming languages allow to modify the HTTP response header. So you can set those header fields manually.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer, You can more specify for me how to modifie header in PHP . And if browser cached a page, it can force broswer refresh ?

Comment: @meotimdihia: Use the [`header` function](http://php.net/header) to modify the HTTP response header. But you cannot force a browser to refresh a page. You can only say that either the response must not be stored at all (i.e. `no-store`) or that it must to be revalidated (i.e. `must-revalidate`). But even in case of the latter you might just get a conditional GET request.

Answer (score 1):

No, your configuration does not affect HTML responses (assuming that you’re not using one of the listed file name extensions).

Besides that, your *Cache-Control* and *Expires* don’t say anything about whether the response may be cached or not. They only say that *if* the response is stored, the stored response is only fresh until the given expiration date is reached; after that the stored response is considered stale.

But in general, [every successful response may be cached unless there are restrictions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.4):

> Unless specifically constrained by a cache-control ([section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)) directive, a caching system MAY always store a successful response (see [section 13.8](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.8)) as a cache entry, MAY return it without validation if it is fresh, and MAY return it after successful validation.

Servers often use expiration dates in the past to indicate that the response is already expired.

Comment: then i should set expire how, when my page view change several hours once

Comment: @meotimdihia: If you know that your page is changed within a fixed interval, you can set the page to expire at that very time (but that’s not possible with mod_expires); or you set the page to expire one hour from the time of access on.